# BigQuery - duplicate rows in query with scoped aggregation

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to run a query that uses *group_concat* function with a scoped aggregation.
The following query returns 175 rows, all with the same values. The duplication seems to be a result of having 175 elements in cell.value

```
SELECT
  ngram,
  group_concat(cell.sample.id) within record con
FROM [publicdata:samples.trigrams] 
where ngram = '! ! That'
```

When adding a new column to query above (*count* with scoped aggregation), the result is one row, as expected. The count row shows the value 175.

```
SELECT
  ngram,
  count(cell.value) within record cnt,
  group_concat(cell.sample.id) within record con
FROM [publicdata:samples.trigrams] 
where ngram = '! ! That'
```

Is seems that the row duplication occurs because there are no values to group (all nulls). If I change the *group_concat* to:

```
group_concat(if(cell.sample.id is null,'',cell.sample.id)) within record con
```

then once again there is only one row.

What is the reason for this?

How can this be avoided without resorting to group by on all columns (which will also require a subquery since it's impossible to combine group by and scoped aggregation functions)?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the query engine.... it should only return 1 row. We're tracking it internally, and hopefully should have a fix soon.